# Source that Amorayim are not required to know Beraitot/Toseftot

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, rishonim, amoroim, talmudic-methodology

I was told that some Rishonim on Sha"s comment that Amorayim were not required to know Beraitot or Toseftot, they only were required to know the Mishna.

Where's that source?

Answer (score 5):

Source Gittin 6b

> אמר רב יוסף מאן לימא לן דר' אביתר בר סמכא הוא ועוד הא איהו דשלח ליה לרב יהודה בני אדם העולין משם לכאן הן קיימו בעצמן (יואל ד, ג) ויתנו (את) הילד בזונה והילדה מכרו ביין וישתו וכתב ליה בלא שירטוט וא"ר יצחק בשתים כותבין שלש אין כותבין במתניתא תנא שלש כותבין ארבע אין כותבין א"ל אביי אטו כל דלא ידע הא דר' יצחק לאו גברא רבה הוא בשלמא מילתא דתליא בסברא לחיי הא גמרא היא וגמרא לא שמיע ליה
>   (Brief Translation) - Rav Yosef asked: " is Rav Evyasar reliable? He didn't know the Braisa that said one cannot write more than 3 words Ashuris hebrew from a Passuk without Sirtut (marking) yet he wrote more than 3 words from a Passuk without Sirtut!"
>   Abayei responded: "if he didn't understand logic he would be unreliable, but here it is Gemora that he did not hear so he is not unreliable."

Comment: Rabbi Yitschak is an amora, not quoted from a barayta

Comment: @ba what does במתניתא תנא mean that is quoted?(Rhetorical question for those that don't have time to analyze posts)

Comment: You're right that Rabbi Evyatar seems to have been unaware of the barayta also, but Abbaye's comment is about his not knowing Rabbi Yitschak

Comment: @ba see Rashi Sukka 28a for term "Gemara" which includes input from tannaim explained in a Mishna and Braisa :גמרא - זו היא סברא שהיו התנאים אחרונים מדקדקים בדברי הראשונים הסתומים לפרשם וליתן בהן טעם כמו שעשו האמוראים אחר התנאים שפירשו דברי התנאים שלפניהן וקבעו בהן גמרא